# Task.Wait in ContinueWhenAll Action

Tags: c#, azure, task, plinq

I was working on encorperating threads into my azure code for putting things on a queue. to do this i used http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19222 as a reference.

my code to enqueue multiple messages looks like this:

```
public void AddMessagesAsync(IEnumerable<IQueueMessage> messages, string queue = null, TimeSpan? timeToLive = null)
{
  //check if we need to switch queues
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(queue))
  {
    SetCurrent(queue);
  }

  //setup list of messages to enqueue
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  Parallel.ForEach(messages, current => {
    if (timeToLive.HasValue)
    {
      //create task with TPL
      var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(Current.BeginAddMessage, Current.EndAddMessage, Convert(current), timeToLive.Value, tasks); 
      //setup continuation to trigger eventhandler
      tasks.Add(task.ContinueWith((t) => AddMessageCompleted(t)));
    }
    else
    {
      //create task with TPL
      var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(Current.BeginAddMessage, Current.EndAddMessage, Convert(current), tasks);
      //setup continuation to trigger eventhandler
      tasks.Add(task.ContinueWith((t) => AddMessageCompleted(t)));
    }
  });

  //setup handler to trigger when all messages are enqueued, a we are blocking the thread over there to wait for all the threads to complete
  Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), (t) => AddMessagesCompleted(t));               
}

private void AddMessagesCompleted(Task[] tasks)
{
  try
  {
    //wait for all tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
  }
  catch (AggregateException e)
  {
    //log the exception
    var ex = e;
    //return ex;
  }

  if (AddedMessages != null)
  {
    AddedMessages(tasks, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Now my question is about the Task.Wait in the continuation (which is according to the document provided by MS). it seems a bit strange to wait for threads where you already know the have completed right? the only reason i can imagine is to bubble the errors and process those. am i missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) will throw an [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) when at least one of the Task instances was canceled -or- an exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances.

[`ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) will not throw this exception and its simply start your last task when everything finishes canceled or not etc.

Comment: i guess we agree on my assumption then?

Comment: @Didier Yeah - forget that part in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I've noticed you are using `List<T>` with `Parallel.ForEach` which is not thread safe, you should replace it with a concurrent collection, eg: [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Regarding `WaitAll` vs `ContinueWhenAll`, `WaitAll` will throw if any of the tasks is faulted, so the code above is to validate all the tasks have completed successfully, you can do the same if you pass `ContinuationOptions` parameter to `ContinueWhenAll` like `OnlyRanToCompeletion` so the continuation task will be scheduled only if all tasks completed successfully.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the pointer about the thread safety.. definite lifesaver.